# How to call cudaMalloc from a separate function?

Tags: cuda

I'm learning cuda and try to write a function that allocate memory on the device in a similar way to that on the host. For example:

```
//host
float* allocate1D_float(int size)
{
    float* array = (float*)malloc(size* sizeof(float));
    if (array==NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Error allocating memory 1\n");
            free(array);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return array;
}
float *h_A = allocate1D_float(numElements);

//device
float* alloc_cuda1D_float(int numElements)
{
    float *d_array = NULL;
    size_t size = numElements * sizeof(float);
    cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;
    err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_array, size);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return d_array;
}
float *d_A = alloc_cuda1D_float(int numElements);
```

However, nvcc keep saying
error: type name is not allowed 
error: expected a ")"
for device function while the host function is ok. Hope you can help me to figure out the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a specific compilation error you need help with, you are going to have to show us the exact code that produces the error, along with the exact command you are using to compile the code and the exact error message the compiler emits when the compilation fails. As it is written, your question is extremely unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding "type name is not allowed":

You did this correctly:

```
float *h_A = allocate1D_float(numElements);
```

But this is wrong:

```
float *d_A = alloc_cuda1D_float(int numElements);
                                ^^^
                                This int shouldn't be here
```

So remove the `int` right in front of `numElements`

This of course has nothing to do with CUDA.  Your host function call would have given a similar error if you attempted to put `int` where it doesn't belong in that call.

Comment: Thanks Robert. This is such an embarrassing mistake! Guess I need coffee.